# How do I merge two programs in Arduino?

Tags: nodemcu

So I have an esp8266 nodemcu which I flashed a program called [Deauther 2.0](https://github.com/spacehuhn/esp8266_deauther). I spent the past two hours trying to merge another [Sketch](https://github.com/dmainmon/ESP8266-OLED-World-Clock-IoT/blob/master/ESP8266_OLED_Clock_IoT.ino). Which I failed miserably.

What I am trying to achieve:

When I first power up my nodemcu it should load the Deauther program. But when I press the built in flash button it should load the second sketch.

What I have tried to fix the problem:

1. Add my own clock.cpp to the Deauther sketch and edited the top part of the sketch:

   ```
   const int button = 0;  

   int temp = 0;

    void setup() {

    pinMode(button, INPUT)

    }

    void loop() {

    temp = digitalRead(button)

    if (temp == HIGH ) {

    // run the code below

   }
   ```
2. Some other stuff which I don't want to mention.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: There's no magic way to merge two sketches. In the general case, it may be impossible. You need to understand what one sketch does and how it does it, understand what the other does and how, and write a third sketch which combines both things. Debug any problems which arise in the usual ways.

Comment: the OP is not talking about merging the two sketches. .... the OP is talking about using one sketch to load another sketch

Comment: Anyone asking a basic question like this has no legitimate use for a WiFi deauther. There are so many amazing things you can do with an ESP8266. Why do you have to chose the malicious usage?

Comment: @per1234 I am not using the deauther for malicious purposes I only test it on my own network.

Answer (score 2):

To be able to merge the sketches you must ensure that both will not try to access the same pins/resource in ways that are incompatible. For example if both need to input from serial you will need to adjust things so the input you send it will reach the correct code.

Once you have made sure of that it is often simplest to first refactor both sketches to avoid any type of delay-like code or anything that halts execution while waiting for something to happen and instead go with state-machine based that just loops constantly and uses timestamps to manage when to actually do stuff.

For example the second sketch has the format:

```
void loop(){
    //do stuff

    delay(1000);
}
```

You should refactor that to

```
unsigned long last_run = 0;

void loop(){
    unsigned long current_millis = millis();
    if(current_millis - last_run > 1000){
        last_run = current_millis;
        //do stuff that never blocks

    }
}
```

Once that is complete and you made sure there is no name conflict between the sketches for the functions/globals you can simply append the `loop()` and `setup()` functions into a new `loop()` and `setup()`